# Calculate formula with data

Tags: r, function, formula

I am new to R and want to calculate this formula (see: link below) with data that I have. I have a different W for all t from t=22 to t=65. Is there a way to apply all the different values automatically?

The goal is to get a single number.I am also not sure if the function that I created is right because for every t there is another W. So, what I want to do with the function is to summarise 1/(1+r)^(t-22) * W for every t and the W that belongs to it. So, for the fifth and sixth row for example it would be 1/(1-r)^(22-22) * 15954. + 1/(1+r)^(23-22) * 18342.

[image]

Here is some sample data:

```
t              W
   <int+lbl>  <dbl>
 1 18         4301.
 2 19         7721.
 3 20        11525.
 4 21        13878.
 5 22        15954.
 6 23        18342.
 7 24        19432.
 8 25        21647.
 9 26        22132.
10 27        23492.
```

Here is also some sample data constructed with dput():

```
structure(list(t = structure(18:22, labels = c(`Less than 1 year old` = 0L, 
`90 (90+ in 1980 and 1990)` = 90L, `100 (100+ in 1960-1970)` = 100L, 
`112 (112+ in the 1980 internal data)` = 112L, `115 (115+ in the 1990 internal data)` = 115L
), label = "Age", var_desc = "AGE reports the person's age in years as of the last birthday.\n\nPlease see the Comparability section regarding a known Universe issue with AGE and AGEORIG which effects EMPSTAT and LABFORCE for the 2004 ACS Sample.", class = c("haven_labelled", 
"vctrs_vctr", "integer")), W = c(4300.83677685951, 7721.46653212248, 
11525.3777996555, 13877.6084883612, 15953.546319797)), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

This is what I tried:

```
rename(earnings_arts_22_65, t = AGE, W = income_mean)

my_function <- function(t, W) {((((1/(1+r))^4 * sum((1/1+r)^(t-22) * W)))-D)(-sum((1/1+r)^(t-18) * W))}

apply(earnings_arts_22_65, 
      FUN = my_function(t, W),
      MARGIN = 2)
```

But I get the following error: Error in t - 22 : non-numeric argument to binary operator.
I don't know why I am getting this error because the variables in the data are also called t and W. r and D have always have same values, which are also defined. Despite from the error, I am unsure if this is the right way to do it anyways.

Thank you very much for helping.

Comment: Most likely you have an error in the apply statement.  You are trying to pass 2 values when only 1 is given.  Try replacing your equation with `print(W)` to verify the passed values.

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems (instead of just the name of the data object you have here). One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Comment: You can use `mapply()` to pass multiple variables to the function. But without sample data it is not possible to illustrate that approach.

Comment: Thank you for the answers, I just added sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to use `mapply()` "multivariate apply" to calculate a formula with two variables.

Regarding error message `non-numeric argument to binary operator`, I received this because `D()` is R's built in Derivatives function.

Error message `Error: attempt to apply non-function` is because there is a missing multiplication sign, for example `(1+2)(3+4)` should be written `(1+2)*(3+4)`.

```
#df <- structure(list(...
r <- 1
D <- 1
my_function <- function(t, W) {((((1/(1+r))^4 * sum((1/1+r)^(t-22) * W)))-D) * (-sum((1/1+r)^(t-18) * W))}

mapply(my_function, df$t, df$W)

#[1]     -67953.84    -916135.90   -8256044.33  -48035983.47 -254260383.44
```

Vectorized addendum: `Vectorize()` is a wrapper around `mapply()` and allows us to use the function like this:

```
my_function_vec<-Vectorize(my_function)
my_function_vec(df$t, df$W)
#[1]     -67953.84    -916135.90   -8256044.33  -48035983.47 -254260383.44
```

Why `sum()` post script: Are the  `sum()` functions in the formula redundant? They are undoing the vectorization in the first place. No apply need:

```
my_function <- function(t, W) {((((1/(1+r))^4 * ((1/1+r)^(t-22) * W)))-D)*(-((1/1+r)^(t-18) * W))}
my_function(df$t, df$W)
#[1]     -67953.84    -916135.90   -8256044.33  -48035983.47 -254260383.44
```

Or is the goal to get a single number?

```
my_function(df$t, df$W) #original formula with sum()
#[1] -728982690
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! The goal is to get a single number. I tried your way to get a single number but got a negative number, which does not make sense with the whole dataset that I used (with the sample data there probably will be a negative number, I guess). I am also not sure if the function that I created is right because for every t there is another W. So, what I want to do with the function is to summarise 1/(1+r)^(t-22) * W for every t and the W that belongs to it. So, for the fifth and sixth row for example it would be 1/(1-r)^(22-22) * 15954.  + 1/(1+r)^(23-22) * 18342.